# Precedence Constraint Stops Foreach Loop Container Execution

Tags: excel, csv, ssis

I am working on an SSIS package where I'm looping through 3 sheets in an Excel file to store all the data in a CSV file.

The first sheet and the third sheet have similar column structure but the 2nd one doesn't.

I want to skip the processing of the 2nd sheet so inside the Foreach Loop Container I have a disabled Expression Task with an expression precedence constraint `@[User::SheetName] == "Sheet1$" || @[User::SheetName] == "Sheet3$"` that connects to the Data Flow Task that does the processing of the Excel file.

My issue is when I execute the package only the first sheet is processed and then execution is completed.

[Image of my Control Flow](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GW3Y9.png)

[Image of my Data Flow](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nux0g.png)

Comment: How about you show us the relevant parts of your code?

Comment: @cybernetic.nomad there isn't any other code, I've edited in pictures of my Control Flow and Data Flow if that helps

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I needed to remove single quotes that were placed around my sheet name variable whenever the sheet name had a space in it.